# Dynamically creating nested DIVs in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to create *nested* divs dynamically, preferably without JavaScript.

So if you have `n` number of DIVs, DIV1 contains DIV1 which contains DIV3 etc…

How would I code that in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

```
function recursiveDiv($num) {

  $html = '<div id="div'.$num.'">%s</div>';

  for($i = $num - 1; $i >= 1; $i--) {
    $html = '<div id="div'.$i.'">'.$html.'</div>';
  }
  return $html;
}

echo sprintf(recursiveDiv(5), 'Hello World');
```

Untested but should give you want you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple loop example using $n = 3. You can change $n to any number and it will nest div tags for you. I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do this, but here it is.

```
$openingTags = '';
$closingTags = '';

$n = 3;

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
    $openingTags .= '<div id="div' . $i . '">';
    $closingTags .= '</div>';
}

echo $openingTags . 'Hello World' . $closingTags;
```

Comment: thx - aim is creating nested divs for yui nested tabview where number of tabs and corresponding nested divs depends on number of rows returned by a query. i ran your code and now am puzzling how to insert content into each div i.e div-1 (somecontent) div-2 (somecontent+) div-3 (somecontent++) /div-3 /div-2 /div-1

Answer (score 1):

This code should allow you to create the nested divs and also populate them with content. Replaced orginal code with below, this should work but its untested

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$html = '';
$end_html = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
  $html .= '<div id="div'.$count.'">'.$row->textfield; # any database column
  $end_html .= '</div>';
  $count--;
}
echo $html . $end_html;
```

Comment: Thx one and all. I had a feeling that it ought to be simple. And it turned out not to be.

Comment: There may well be a more simple solution than mine, its just the first thing that came to my head, is there anything in particular that you dont understand? if you want dynamic content you could dynamically generate the array you parse to my function.

Comment: After reading your comment from @Sohnee's code I have modified the code to create an array from a query, hope this helps

Comment: hi Luke - thx for simpler to look at code. Dynamic nested tabview w yui ought to be do-able now.  Tom

Comment: dropped yr code into a page to check: it works v well. 

question: removing the . from the = kills the recursive effect: can I ask you how the .= does its magic ?

Comment: $html .= 'luke' is the same as $html = $html . 'luke'  so it concatenates rather than replaces.

Comment: Got it!  Soooo the php whiles away adding as it were little snips of the same html together i.e <div3>content3 <div2>content2 <div1>content1  giving the required nesting etc    thx again!

Comment: Hi Luke,thanks for your codes,in a search i reached to you and it solved my problem,but would you please let me know that ,why you have used 2 variables for creating <div>($html and $end_html)?

Comment: Hi @Kaveh, I used 2 variables because of the nested nature of the html structure.  If I just added the closing div tag to the end of `$html` in the loop then it would not produce nested code.  We need to open all of the divs first and then close them all at the end i.e `open open open close close close`, not `open close, open close...`. I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

While others are suggesting using mathematical solutions based on [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loops, you can do this a bit more explicitly—clearly setting classnames—by using an array like this:

```
// Set the DIVs array.
$divs_array = array();
$divs_array[] = 'DIV1';
$divs_array[] = 'DIV2';
$divs_array[] = 'DIV3';
```

Now with that array set, you can use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) to take the content of those arrays and set them as DIV class values like this. Note the `implode` logic might seem confusing, but look at what it creates and look at how the code is set and it makes more sense after a while:

```
// Set the DIVs.
$div_opening = $div_closing = '';
if (!empty($divs_array)) {
  $div_opening = '<div class="' . implode($divs_array, '">' . "\n" . '<div class="') . '">';
  $div_closing = '</div><!-- .' . implode(array_reverse($divs_array), '-->' . "\n" . '</div><!-- .') . ' -->';
}
```

And then you can set the content between the `$div_opening` and `$div_closing` values like this:

```
// Return the content wrapped in the DIVs.
echo $div_opening
   . '<p>Hello world.</p>'
   . $div_closing
   ;
```

The output would be something like this:

```
<div class="DIV1">
<div class="DIV2">
<div class="DIV3">
<p>Hello world.</p>
</div><!-- .DIV3 -->
</div><!-- .DIV2 -->
</div><!-- .DIV1 -->
```

Note my personal coding style is to—whenever possible—set comments after each DIV that clearly shows what that `</div>` is actually closing. So that is what the comments like `<!-- .DIV3 -->` refer to; feel free to adjust to fit your own coding needs and style.